# Visual Studio - Windows forms designer unable to load form (error)

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

The designer could not be shown for this file because none of the classes within it can be designed. The designer inspected the following classes in the file: Form1 --- The base class 'System.' could not be loaded. Ensure the assembly has been referenced and that all projects have been built.

```
Instances of this error (1)  
 
1.   Show Call Stack  
 
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.EnsureDocument(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.BasicDesignerLoader.BeginLoad(IDesignerLoaderHost host)
```

Help with this error

MSDN Help

Forum posts about this error

Search the MSDN Forums for posts related to this error

[image]

Comment: is your solution a new one? what version of VS you are using?

Comment: Read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The title is inappropriate, and the question could be better stated.

Comment: is your solution a new one? what version of VS you are using? Please check the properties of your project and see what is the target framework.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask].

Comment: This is known problem https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/cannot-display-inherited-form-in-form-designer-when-base-form-defined-in-64-bit-assembly-29ca1d78-f6e6-24d3-37e2-f1d918037ebf

Answer (score -1):

In your code you should not define a class (like: `myclass`) before the class `Form1`.

To solve the issue move the class `myclass` below the class `Form1`. Or, in other words, the class where your Form is defined should be the first class in the file.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
 public class myclass
 {
    int mymember;
 }
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
    public Form1()
   {
            InitializeComponent();
    }
 }
}
```

Also note that in the error list (menu: View/Error List) is a message:

> The class Form1 can be designed, but is not the first class in the
> file.

[image]

BTW: Next time please provide more info, and not just the text from the error message. This will help to identify the problem easier...

Comment: Agree; or move the myclass out to another file

Comment: @CaiusJard: that would be lesson2, and he just started with lesson1 